# Angularjs Handle api timeout

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to throw error when api doesn't respond within 30 seconds.

```
$http.get("api/data.json",{timeout : 3000}).success(function(data){
            $scope.data = data;
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log('api didnt respond in 30 seconds')
        });
```

But it doesnt land in the error block even after 30 seconds.
I am new to angularjs. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a promise to the $http timeout property:

```
    app.controller('ctrl', function ($http, $timeout) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/data.json',
            timeout: $timeout(function () { alert('request timed out'); }, 3000)
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert('request successful');
        });
    });
```